# How do I display my program in my own created window?

Tags: java, string, swing, console, jframe

```
import java.util.*;
public class RockPaperScissors {

    public String toGenerate() {
        String x = null;
        Random generator = new Random();
        int y = generator.nextInt(2);

        switch (y) {
        case 0 : x = "Rock"; break;
        case 1 : x = "Paper"; break;
        case 2 : x = "Scissors"; break;
        }
        return x ;
    }

    public void toDisplayResult(String x , String y) {
        String comp = x;
        String c = y;
        c = c.toLowerCase();
        comp = comp.toLowerCase();

        if(comp.equals(c))
            System.out.print("\nDRAW !!!");
        else if(comp.equals("rock") && c.equals("paper"))  //Not Excuting
            System.out.print("\nYou WIN !!!");
        else if(comp.equals("rock") && (c.equals("scissors") || c.equals("scissor")))
            System.out.print("\nYou LOSE !!!");
        else if(comp.equals("scissors") && c.equals("paper"))
            System.out.print("\nYou LOSE !!!");
        else if(comp.equals("scissors") && c.equals("rock"))
            System.out.print("\nYou WIN !!!");
        else if(comp.equals("paper") && (c.equals("scissor") || c.equals("scissors")))
            System.out.print("\nYou WIN !!!");
        else if(comp.equals("paper") && c.equals("rock"))
            System.out.print("\nYou LOSE !!!");

    }

    public void toIntroduce() {
        System.out.println("Hi !!! Welcome To \"The ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS\" v0.0508\nDeveloped By Saikat Das\nInstagram : @saikat._");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RockPaperScissors obj = new RockPaperScissors();
        Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = null;
        obj.toIntroduce();
        System.out.println();

        do {
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice : ");
        String c = in.next();
        String comp = obj.toGenerate();
        System.out.print(comp);
        System.out.println();

        obj.toDisplayResult(comp, c);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Press \"Y\" To Play Again OR \"N\" To Quit ");
        x = in.next();
        System.out.println();

        }while(x.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

        System.out.println("Thanks For Playing !!!");
        System.out.println("Hope You Enjoyed This Epic Game");
        System.out.println("More Updates Will Be Coming");
        System.out.println("Follow Me ON Instagram And Stay Tuned !!!");
    }

}
```

I have also learned to make windows using JFrame. But I don't have any clue how to just display it in my created window.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Windows extends Canvas{
    public void window() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        Canvas canvas = new Windows();
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        canvas.setSize(800, 600);
        window.add(canvas);
        window.pack();
        window.setTitle("This Is My Own Window");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Windows obj = new Windows();
        obj.window();

    }

}
```

I was also thinking if this method is even possible, if not then how can I do it?

Comment: you need to write again , System.out.println is meant for printing on the console you can use it to print on a Jcomponent

Comment: What else i write ???

Comment: you need to learn about the swing package , then you will know what to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in another comment, you certainly need to add another library. I would recommend importing `javax.swing.JOptionPane` and learning from there. There are multiple different things from there, but in general just import that and you can show a message by doing the following:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your message here");
```

There are certainly other ways to go about it though. I'm not familiar with `JFrame` myself. If you're just looking for the basics then `JOptionPane` is your best bet.